# EMF: Restricting choices to predefined values

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I am using EMF to allow users to create instances of a particular type of model.

An instance of a model can have 0-* Things but I'd like to be able to predefine the available Things that the user can add to the instance so that they can't just create their own.

How would I go about creating the Things using the ecore model?

If a Thing was just a String then it would be fine - I could use Enums. But a Thing is a type of it's own and consists of other stuff (like a name, version etc.) and I don't know how to give a predefined set of these to the user to choose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have the possibility to use constraints or *EOperation*s.

For a better usability you should use a own dialog implementation. An example of a own implementation with given choices you can find here:
[How can I control which instances are available as choices when editing a property in the properties view?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/EMF-FAQ#How_can_I_control_which_instances_are_available_as_choices_when_editing_a_property_in_the_properties_view.3F)

You should also implement a own property source to support the properties editor:
[Recipe: Create your own property editor in a generated application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/Recipes#Recipe%3a_Create_your_own_property_editor_in_a_generated_application)